# Bad quality of image after resize

Tags: php, jquery, image

I'm trying to resize my images after upload, but the image quality suffers.

I've tested two 2 sets of code:

```
$im = new imagick($filename); 
$im->setImageResolution(1250,1250);
$im->setImageColorspace(255);
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setCompressionQuality(100);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeImage('thumb.jpg');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

and this:

```
$newwidth = 460;
$newheight = 275;
$newwidth1 = 146;
$newheight2 = 88;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
imagecopyresampled($temp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
Imagettftext($temp, 16, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black2, $font , "text");
imagejpeg($temp, $path,75);
imagedestroy($temp);

$temp2 = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1, $newheight2);
imagecopyresampled($temp2, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth1, $newheight2, $width, $height);
Imagettftext($temp2, 8, 0, $start_x2, $start_y2, $black2, $font , "text");
imagejpeg($temp2,$pathFile ,75);
imagedestroy($temp2);
imagedestroy($src);
```

None of them are working as I'd like. Any advice?

Comment: Of course the quality is less with re-size. What did you expect?

Comment: How are they 'bad quality'? can you post a sample? imagick has `imagick::COMPRESSION_LOSSLESSJPEG`

Answer (score 0):

For ImageMagick and setCompressionQuality(), according to the PHP documentation:

> This method only works for new images e.g. those created through Imagick::newPseudoImage. For existing images you should use Imagick::setImageCompressionQuality().

So setImageCompressionQuality should do the trick.

For your GD-example: 75 is actually quite low for GD. What value is reasonable depends highly on the used library, and I would suggest at least 85 for GD - this will still be a high compression value, while the quality will not suffer too much, otherwise you should just set it higher. If you have specific requirements for picture quality, testing some values is probably necessary.